# CSS linking order and overruling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Sometimes I encounter this problem where a CSS rule from a higher line of CSS file link overrules a CSS rule from a lower line of CSS file link.

Let me demonstrate, this is the order of loaded files:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/datepicker.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/fonts.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-select.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/media_queries.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/hover.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/print.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
```

In my `styles.css` file I add a rule as such:

```
dd {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

When I check my *Google Developers Console* I see this:
[image]

So, the only conclusion I have from this is that general styles **do not** overrule media queries. Is this true? What is the best practice to overrule this bootstrap media query? by writing the same query or using `!important`?

<kbd>Thanks</kbd>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS rules are applied based on "Specificity". This includes criteria such as order of appearance, how specific your css selectors are, and a few other.

I would not be so quick to jump to the `!important` rule, because this implies you've not understood *why* your css does not apply the way you want. There's a nice write-up about it on [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) which you will want to read to understand the subject better.

In your specific example, the `@media` query is not the actual culprit here (although it seems to apply), it's the fact that the `.dl-horizontal dd` rule is **more specific** than the generic `dd` rule, and therefor "wins". Without repeating what the linked article explains, your conclusion that

> general styles do not overrule media queries

is incorrect, as the case is that you have (at least) two css rules targetting your `dd`, where *one is more specific than the other*, and therefore "wins", regardless of the `@media` prefix.

Comment: I see Daniel, thank you very much for your fast response and the reference.

Answer (score 2):

If the console screenshot you provided you can see the two CSS selectors:

```
.dl-horizontal dd {}
dd {}
```

The reason that `.dl-horizontal dd` overrides your `dd` CSS, is because CSS works on the basis of specificity. `.dl-horizontal dd` is more specific that `dd` and therefore is the active style.

Using `!important` isn't the answer, you simply need to right your CSS selector to be more specific than `.dl-horizontal dd`. Any example may be;

```
dl.dl-horizontal dd { margin-left: 0; }
```

Comment: I see @itsphilz, thank you very much for your details response. :)